Initiliazation of members in case of multiple inheritance
I have the following architecture
#include <iostream>

class A_Base {
public:
    A_Base () : foo(14) { }
    
protected:
    int foo;
    // In my real case, A_Base has a lot of members
};

class A_Derived : public A_Base {
public:   
    A_Derived () { foo = 15; }
};

class B_Base : A_Base {
public:
    B_Base() {}
    
    void print_foo () { std::cout << foo << std::endl; } 
    /* B_base has a lots of methods that use A_base members */
};

class B_Derived : public B_Base, A_Derived {
public:
    B_Derived() {}
};

int main()
{
    B_Base bar = B_Derived();
    
    bar.print_foo(); // Prints 14

    return 0;
}

In my real case, A_Base has a lot of members, that are initialized in multiple derived classes.
When calling an inherited function from B_Base  in B_Derived, I am expecting members intialized in A_Derived to be used. And it appears they are not initialized properly.
So how can I make foo to be intialized at 15 when using B_Derived as a B_Base ?

you have a diamond problem see how to fix diamond problem

Re: "A_Base has a lot of members, that are initialized in multiple derived classes" -- derived classes cannot initialize base class members. The constructor of the base class initializes all of the base class's members. Derived classes might assign new values to base class members, but that's not initialization.

That's exactly the same problem as your previous question. bar has two variables called foo. One inherited through B_Base and the other through A_Derived. One of them has value 14, the other value 15. B_Base only sees one of them.

But how can I deal with this problem ?

@AhmedAEK No it aint a diamond problem

This class hierarchy has two base sub-objects of type A_Base; one comes from B_Base and the other comes from A_Derived. That's a perfectly reasonable design. If you only wan tone A_Base sub-object, both B_Base and A_Derived (very confusing name here), should inherit A_Base virtually.

you can call it the topaz problem, it doesn't change the details or the solution to the problem.

It indeed is a diamond problem. Though it's usually explained with functions, since Java prefers to have a getFoo() instead of accessing foo directly.

@AhmedAEK virtualising any class inheritance here would not solve this issue

it definitely will, online example

@AhmedAEK ok sorry I tested the solution incorrectly

by the way B_Base bar = B_Derived(); is probably not what you want: you sliced the B_Derived object. You can make bar a reference instead. (not related to the diamond issue)

What is the point of B_Derived in your example? How does the demonstration of the problem fail if you drop B_Derived from your question and instead instantiate B_base directly?

@Oersted what is the point to do that?

@JaMiT In my real case, B_base is abstract, and can't be instantiated. devired class are decided durring runtime, and can't be predicted

@AhmedAEK please answer with the solution so we can close this topic

@tony_merguez "In my real case," -- This is not relevant to your question. You already eliminate the pure virtual functions for this question; the next step is to eliminate B_Derived. Don't stop simplifying before you're done.

object slicing.

slicing example

btw adding a ref is not enough, as you cannot bind a non const ref to a temporary. You'll have to take the address of a newly allocated object for instance. But again its not related to your question.

this is a Diamond Problem and any duplicated base needs to be virtually inherited by its derived class, in this case A_Base is duplicated, therefore all places where it is inherited needs to be marked virtual.
class A_Base {
public:
    A_Base () : foo(14) { }
    
protected:
    int foo;
    // In my real case, A_Base has a lot of members
};

class A_Derived : public virtual A_Base {
public:   
    A_Derived () { foo = 15; }
};

class B_Base : virtual A_Base {
public:
    B_Base() {}
    
    void print_foo () { std::cout << foo << std::endl; } 
    /* B_base has a lots of methods that use A_base members */
};


online example
